Quarkus Vertx JDBC Logging issue
I had a vertx application, I migrated to quarkus. To not reimplement everything from scratch I reuse my vertx verticles in quarkus, and these verticles uses vertx-jdbc to access a database. It looks good so far and everythink seams to work except that I see a lot of warnings in the logs which makes reading logs impossible.
Versions I use:
quarkus: 2.16.12 (cannot migrate to 3.x yet cause I use kogito)
vertx: 4.3.7
The lines which are being logged over and over again are:
2024-05-21 21:34:03,598 WARN  [com.mch.v2.c3p.imp.NewPooledConnection] (vert.x-worker-thread-1) [c3p0] A PooledConnection that has already signalled a Connection error is still in use!
2024-05-21 21:34:03,598 WARN  [com.mch.v2.c3p.imp.NewPooledConnection] (vert.x-worker-thread-1) [c3p0] Another error has occurred [ java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported method ] which will not be reported to     listeners!: java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported method
        at jdbc.gupta.sqlbase.SqlbaseResultSet.getObject(SqlbaseResultSet.java:2302)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyResultSet.getObject(NewProxyResultSet.java:217)
        at io.vertx.ext.jdbc.spi.impl.JDBCDecoderImpl.lambda$parse$0(JDBCDecoderImpl.java:62)
        at io.vertx.ext.jdbc.spi.impl.JDBCDecoderImpl.decodeNumber(JDBCDecoderImpl.java:217)
        at io.vertx.ext.jdbc.spi.impl.JDBCDecoderImpl.decode(JDBCDecoderImpl.java:89)
        at io.vertx.ext.jdbc.spi.impl.JDBCDecoderImpl.parse(JDBCDecoderImpl.java:62)
        at io.vertx.ext.jdbc.impl.actions.AbstractJDBCAction.asList(AbstractJDBCAction.java:81)
        at io.vertx.ext.jdbc.impl.actions.JDBCQuery.execute(JDBCQuery.java:59)
        at io.vertx.ext.jdbc.impl.actions.JDBCQuery.execute(JDBCQuery.java:30)
        at io.vertx.ext.jdbc.impl.JDBCConnectionImpl.lambda$schedule$3(JDBCConnectionImpl.java:219)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextBase.lambda$null$0(ContextBase.java:137)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextInternal.dispatch(ContextInternal.java:264)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextBase.lambda$executeBlocking$1(ContextBase.java:135)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.TaskQueue.run(TaskQueue.java:76)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
        at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
        at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)

I wonder what causes these logs and if it is possible to mute them so it is not flooding my logs. By the way: it is correct that my Gupta SQLBase JDBC driver throws an SQLException("unsupported method") for the method being called.
Thank you and best regards,
Marco
